# Steps to calculate the tangential acceleration and normal acceleration of a vector

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

I am given $r(t) = \langle\cos(3) , 1 − \sin(3) , 3 \sin(3) + \cos(3)\rangle$ and $t= \pi /4$

I have calculated $r'(t)$ and  $r''(t)$.

I don't know what to do next to get either tangential or normal acceleration component. Any pointers?

Comment: Can you find the acceleration vector by itself?   Then, can you find the tangent direction and project the acceleration vector onto that direction?

Comment: The acceleration vector is the second derivative, right?

Comment: @SgZQoy9jhG:  you are correct, the acceleration vector is $\ddot r(t)$; see my answer below.  ***Cheers!***

Answer (score 1):

For any *regular* curve  $r(t)$, the velocity is $\dot r(t)$; this vector is clearly tangent to $r(t)$ for every $t$; the acceleration vector is evidently $\ddot r(t)$, but it is not in general tangent to $r(t)$.  We may find both the tangential and normal components of $\ddot r(t)$; first, we form the *unit tangent vector field* $T(t)$ to $r(t)$:

$T(t) = \dfrac{\dot r(t)}{\vert \dot r(t) \vert}, \tag 1$

where we have used the assumed regularity if $r(t)$ that is,

$\dot r(t) \ne 0, \tag 2$

in order to form $T(t)$, since (2) is equivalent to

$\vert \dot r(t) \vert \ne 0. \tag 3$

The tangential component of any vector field $v(t)$ along $r(t)$ is then

$v_T(t) = (v(t) \cdot T(t)) T(t); \tag 4$

in particular, taking

$v(t) = \ddot r(t), \tag 5$

we see that the tangential component of the acceleration is

$\ddot r_T(t) = (\ddot r(t) \cdot T(t)) T(t); \tag 6$

the component of acceleration normal to $r(t)$ is thus

$\ddot r_N(t) = \ddot r(t) - \ddot r_T(t) = \ddot r(t) - (\ddot r(t) \cdot T(t)) T(t); \tag 7$

indeed we see that

$\ddot r(t) = \ddot r_T(t) + \ddot r_N(t), \tag 8$

and

$\ddot r_N(t) \cdot T(t) = \ddot r(t) \cdot T(t) - (\ddot r(t) \cdot T(t)) T(t) \cdot T(t)$
$= \ddot r(t) \cdot T(t) - (\ddot r(t) \cdot T(t))  = 0.  \tag 9$

We note that $\ddot r_T(t)$ and $\ddot r_N(t)$ may both be expressed solely in terms of $r(t)$, that is, without explicit reference to $T(t)$.  We substitute (1) into (6):

$\ddot r_T(t) = \left (\ddot r(t) \cdot \dfrac{\dot r(t)}{\vert \dot r(t) \vert} \right ) \dfrac{\dot r(t)}{\vert \dot r(t) \vert} = \dfrac{\ddot r(t) \cdot \dot r(t)}{\vert \dot r(t) \vert^2}\dot r(t), \tag{10}$

and also into (7):

$\ddot r_N(t) = \ddot r(t) - \ddot r_T(t) = \ddot r(t) - \left (\ddot r(t) \cdot \dfrac{\dot r(t)}{\vert \dot r(t) \vert} \right ) \dfrac{\dot r(t)}{\vert \dot r(t) \vert}$
$= \ddot r(t) - \dfrac{\ddot r(t) \cdot \dot r(t)}{\vert \dot r(t) \vert^2}\dot r(t). \tag{11}$

I leave calculating $\ddot r_T(t)$ and $\ddot r_N(t)$ for the specific curve given in the text of the question itself to the sufficiently engaged amongst my readers; it is not difficult.